# Why does this code write to file ok in iOS 7.0.6 but not in 7.1.2?

Tags: xcode6

In IOS 7.1.2 I get Cocoa error 513 which I know is a permissions error but all permissions for var, mobile & Documents are exactly the same on each phone.

```
NSString *newLocString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%f\n%s%f","Lat=",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,"Long=",currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
NSString *path = @"var/mobile/Documents/myLocation.txt";
NSError *error = nil;

// Save string and check for error
if (![newLocString writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"An Error occurred: %@", error.localizedDescription);

} else {

UIAlertView *savedAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!"message:@"The myLocation.txt file was updated." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[savedAlert show];
}
```